# IE9 issue - Required MultipartFile[] parameter is not present with Jquery-uploadify

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have angular Spring MVC application, where i am using jquery-uploadify plugin to upload files. Below is the code

The different js files i have included

```
<!--  files for image uploader extension  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/uploadHandler.js"></script>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE8+ -->
<!--[if gte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Below is the javascipt to load the file upload.

```
 $(this).fileupload({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: uploadSettings.upload_url,
            type: 'POST'
});
```

This code works fine in IE10+, chrome, firefox

> But it fails on IE9

and gives -  Required MultipartFile[] parameter is not present on server

Please suggest what is the possible fix for this

Comment: Do you specify 1 option about: html5,flash. I forget the name of it.

Comment: No i haven't specified any such option, can you please describe this option

Comment: we use it in our project, it works well in IE8. Actually at first it just works in FF, we configed an option so it works in IE8. But now I'm out of office. I will check the code and give you more infomation tomorrow. The option is just like this: seems IE8 doesn't support html5, so when the plug-in works in IE, it will use flash instead of html5

Comment: Okk thanks, i'll look forward to your answer

Comment: I also found some thing in its' website， check it out: http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/comment/16896

Comment: Buddy, I made a mistake. We use plupload not uploadify. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the below javascript file, which solved the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jqueryUploadify/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
```