# Unable to Upload File to Spring MVC using Web API

Tags: c#, spring-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to upload a file using **.Net** Framework 4.5 and Web API  to a 3rd party client that uses Spring MVC to handle their file uploads. Every attempt is met with the error, "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present."

Has anyone else ran into this issue? If so how did you resolve it? It doesn't seem like Web API offers the proper mechanism/container to send to Spring so that it will recognize it.

Here is the current code.

```
 Uri webService = new Uri(objectInstance);

            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("taleotest.xml")));//new ByteArrayContent(new byte[100]);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("file")
            {
                FileName = @"C:\taleotest.xml"
            };

            var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                                            {
                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "test"),
                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("title", "test2")
                                            });
            //fileContent.add
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            cookieContainer.Add(webService, new Cookie("authToken", _authToken));
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

            MultipartContent content = new MultipartContent();
            content.Add(formData);
            content.Add(fileContent);

            var response = httpClient.PostAsync(webService, content).Result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the content of my request did the trick.

```
string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n"); // Encoding
            byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `CommonsMultipartResolver` property value to your `applicationContext.xml` file? http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?66240-Problems-with-MultipartFile-Upload

Can you ensure all dependencies have been correctly referenced? Example of one: [IE9 issue - Required MultipartFile[] parameter is not present with Jquery-uploadify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449738/ie9-issue-required-multipartfile-parameter-is-not-present-with-jquery-upload)

Might need some more information and code examples to provide more help, this can be caused by many things.